# How long can I leave a vegan chili simmering without components breaking down?

Tags: cooking-time, chili

Tomorrow I'm participating in an amateur just-for-fun chili competition my work is putting on. Unfortunately, the tasting starts immediately after work. My question is, when can I make my chili and how long can I leave it in my crockpot without the ingredients breaking down? It will be a vegan chili, so the components I'm most worried about are the quinoa and green bell pepper. The longest I've cooked a chili was ~4 hours so I really have no idea how long is "okay" before everything starts turning to mush.

My options are to make the chili tonight, tomorrow in the early morning, or skip out on work tomorrow afternoon if absolutely necessary. If I make the chili ahead of time, should I refrigerate it until a few hours before the competition and then heat it up in my crockpot or should I keep it simmering all day/night long?

Comment: Definitely make it the night before, chilli benefits from a little time to mature. I always think it tastes 10x better when it's reheated.